# How to reuse code (function) in c++

Tags: c++, oop

Hello I am writing a string class in c++ and i want to reuse operator+(const string& string1) in operator+(const char *) and reuse operator + and operator= for string operator +=( const string& string1) and operator+=(const char *). My code is as below. Thanks everyone :)

```
String& String::operator=(const String& string1) {
    using std::nothrow;
    using std::endl;
    using std:: cout;

    destroy();
    size = string1.getSize();
         // if (*this != string1){
    if (getSize() != 0)
    {
       data = new (nothrow) char[getSize()];
       if (data == NULL)
         cout<<" ERROR message not enough memory allocated)"<<endl;
       else
       {
          for (unsigned int i = 0; i < getSize(); i++)
            data[i] = string1.data[i];
       }
    }
    return *this;
}

String& String::operator=(const char * cstring) {

    String temp(cstring);
    temp = *this;
    return temp;
}

String& String::operator +(const String& string1){ 
    using std::nothrow;
    using std::endl;
    using std:: cout;


    String temp;
    //destroy();
    //char * temp = new char[size];

    temp.size = getSize() + string1.getSize();
    //char * temp = new char[size];

        if (getSize() != 0)
        {

            temp.data = new (nothrow) char[getSize()];

        if (temp.data == NULL)
        {
            cout<< "ERROR"<<endl;
        }
        else
        {

        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < temp.getSize(); i++)
            temp.data[i]= data[i];

        int j = 0;
        for (unsigned int i = temp.getSize(); i < string1.getSize(); i++)
        {
           temp.data[i] = string1.data[j];
           j++;
        }
    }   
}
  return temp;
}

String& String::operator+(const char *string1){

   //not correct. i have to resue operator +
   String temp (string1);
   (*this)+();
return (temp)
}
String & String::operator+=(const char *string1){
// I have to reuse operator + and operator =

//String temp (string1);
//(*this)+(temp);
return (temp)
```

}

Comment: So what is the issue?

Comment: generally, `+` uses `+=`.

Comment: Your assignment operator breaks on self assignment.

Comment: C++ needs many things. But none if them is *yet another* string class.

Comment: How's that related to [tag:c++11] or [tag:c++14] specifically?

Comment: Is it OK to return a local variable by reference? Like this code is repeatedly doing with "temp".

Comment: @bkVnet allowed, but not at all OK

Comment: @JesperJuhl Even after `std::string_view` lands there are still plenty of string classes that need to be written for various ownership and layout guarantees.

Answer (score 0):

As long as your string type has a constructor that takes `const char*` you'll get these for free. The compiler will convert C-style strings to your string type with that constructor wherever it needs your string type. For example,

```
String346 str("abcd");
String346 res = str + "efgh";
```

This will store `"abcdefgh"` in `res`, using the member function `operator+(const String346&)`.

However, that's not a good interface for `operator+`, for several reasons. Instead, as some of the comments suggest, make `operator+=` a member function, define `operator+(const String346&, const String346&)` as a free function, and implement it with `operator+=`.

If you do that, the conversion will still work.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I appreciate

Comment: Also im suppose to make both operator + and operator += member functions

Comment: @isaac_34 -- okay, ignore the last two paragraphs of my answer. <g>